# How to get the primary key of collection objects?

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-collection

I have a collection of attributes which was made by combining several tables. I want to get the primary key of the objects resides in this collection. Any suggestions would be helpful,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you have an item from a collection calling `->getId()` on the item will return the primary key value of that item.

To get the name of the field from a certain collection the following snippet should help

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('namespace/...')->getCollection();
echo $collection->getResource()->getIdFieldName();
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. It returns the primary key column name. What if the primary key is not an auto increment field? Is this getId() still be valid?

Comment: Hm it should be an autoincrement field, otherwise you'll run into issues on save :)

Comment: One more clarification plz. Can we use primary key field which is not an auto increment value in an admin grid?

Comment: You probably could, never tried it but you run a high risk of error

Comment: Thanks again. I tried. It didn't work for the grid. Thanks a lot and +1

Comment: No problem. Glad to help